# Shrink Windows partition to install Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, dual-boot

I want to install Fedora 20 along already installed Windows 8.1 on my notebook. I found a good how-to on [Techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_Fedora_Linux_on_a_Windows_System_%28Dual_booting%29#Beginning_the_Dual_Boot_Installation_Process), however, the installer for Fedora 20 looks completely different, is simpler (*cough* more *cough* stupid *cough*), and doesn't offer the partition shrink. So I'm looking for a best way how to do it **without destroying my Windows** (since they came with the notebook and I can't re-install).

I think that once I manage to shrink the partition and create enough empty space on the disk, the Fedora installer will be happy, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advise you boot to Windows. From within windows, first back up your data.

Next defragment the hard drive.

Then, from within windows, resize you windows partition. Leave free space uppartitioned.

[image]

Boot Fedora and run the installer, install into the free space.

From the Ubuntu Forums post:

1. disable pagefile: Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> [Performance] Settings... -> Advanced tab -> [Virtual memory] Change... -> uncheck Automatically manage paging file size for all drives -> select No paging file -> Set -> Yes -> OK...
2. disable hibernation file (hiberfil.sys): lower left corner rt click -> Command Prompt (Admin) -> powercfg /h off ["powercfg /h on" to turn it back on]
3. disable system restore: Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> System protection -> select Local Disk (C:)(System) -> Configure... -> Disable system protection
4. disable writing debugging information: Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> [Startup and Recovery] Settings -> change Write debugging information from Automatic memory dump to none
5. disk cleanup: Control Panel -> System and Security -> Free up disk space [at bottom] -> check everything -> OK
6. reboot
7. defragment: Control Panel -> System and Security -> Defragment and optimize your drives [under Administrative Tools]
8. reboot
9. shrink Windows partition to ~100GB with Disk Management
10. reenable pagefile, hibernation file, system restore, and debugging info

Comment: Can windows resize the partition it is currently running from?

Comment: Yes, see http://www.tweakhound.com/2013/01/02/how-to-resize-your-windows-8-partition/ IMO this method is much less error prone.

Comment: Cool! Could you add some info to your answer explaining how it can be done?

Comment: Managed to use it. However, I had to use a [how-to on ubuntuforums by **parminides**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087466) about disabling all unmovable stuff on the disk, to allow significant shrink.

Answer (score 3):

I find it *very* hard to believe that the Fedora installer does not offer this option. In fact, according to [this](http://www.zdnet.com/fedora-20s-anaconda-installer-hands-on_p7-7000024398/#photo) it does. It is probably hidden in an "Advanced" tab somewhere, look around for "Manual partitioning" or similar.

Another option would be to resize your partition using something like [PartedMagic](https://partedmagic.com/) which will allow you to boot into a live session and resize your Windows partition there. Once you have shrunk your Windows partition, reboot and load the Fedora installer again.

I have done this and similar things many times and have never had a problem, nevertheless, whenever you resize partitions you should **always make sure you have a recent backup** of your important data.

Comment: The fedora installer does not give the option to resize partitions, you have to resize prior to running the installer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen are you sure? That seems extremely strange and according to [this](http://www.zdnet.com/fedora-20s-anaconda-installer-hands-on_p7-7000024398/#photo) it does.

Comment: According to the fedora 20 install guide it does not http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Installation_Guide/Disk_Space-x86.html I would resize the windows partition from within windows.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I ask again, can Windows actually do that? How can it resize a mounted partition that the system is currently using? Anyway the docs are misleading, the OP found the same option as in the link I gave in my previous comment so the installer _can_ resize partitions.

Comment: Yes, windows can do this and IMO it is more reliable to do so from within windows, see the link I gave.

Comment: @ferdon There can be unmovable stuff on the W8 partition, therefore I had to use the solution by bodhi, with added steps as I commented below the answer. Sorry for not accepting yours :(

Comment: @tohecz glad you could get it to work, don't apologize, you should accept whichever answer best solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

After I shrunk the volume in Windows by a disappointing amount, the option to shrink the volume in the Fedora 20 installer became available allowing me to shrink it down by much more.

**Shrink the volume in Windows**
1. Boot into Windows
2. Go to "Disk Management"
    a. Right click "Computer" from the desktop or Start Menu
    b. Click on "Manage"
    c. On the left pane, click on "Disk Management"
3. Shrink your Windows volume
    a. Right click on the volume "OS (C:)" in the top or bottom pane
    b. Click on "Shrink Volume..."
    c. Enter the amount you want to shrink the volume by
        i. If you are allowed to shrink it by the desired amount, congratulations, you're almost done
        ii. If not, leave the value alone and we will shrink it down further later
    d. Click the "Shrink" button

**Shrink the volume again in the Fedora installer**
By shrinking the volume first in Windows, this seems to allow the Fedora installer to shrink the volume, too.  If you weren't able to shrink the Windows volume down enough, you should be able to shrink it further here.

On my 256 GB hard drive, Windows' Disk Management allowed me to shrink the Windows volume down to 125 GB.  Afterwards, the Fedora installer allowed me to take it down to as low as 25 GB if I wanted to.  I decided on leaving Windows with 80 GB.

After I booted into Windows again, it performed a disk check and then everything was fine.  Funnily enough, at this point Windows' Disk Management also allowed me to shrink the volume down to 25 GB if I wanted to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be succinct.

Comment: +1 . Welcome to U & L SE :) Thanks for providing more details to your answer. :) This will definitely help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 20 install can resize a Windows partition, but it's kind of obscure. First, you need to have insufficient space on the selected drive. You then have to proceed with the installation, *then* Fedora will tell you the free space on the drive is too small but will offer custom partitioning or guided resizing. Click the latter button, and you'll get a nice slider to choose how much to shrink the partition.

You can also run the included parted command-line utility in a Terminal window, although I did not try this.